# Same Java code Failed to run under Java Gradle Application

Tags: java, gradle, netbeans, nosuchelementexception

I have come across an issue when running the following code under Netbeans Gradle Java Application.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class Main {
    private static int imgBundle;
    private static int flacBundle;
    private static int vidBundle;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        takeInput();
    }
    private static void takeInput() {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Please enter the number of Image format for the order: ");
        imgBundle = input.nextInt();     // where the error occurred
        System.out.print("Please enter the number of Audio format for the order: ");
        flacBundle = input.nextInt();    // where the error occurred
        System.out.print("Please enter the number of Video format for the order: ");
        vidBundle = input.nextInt();     // where the error occurred
        System.out.println("Your Order Input:");
        System.out.println(imgBundle + " IMG");
        System.out.println(flacBundle + " FLAC");
        System.out.println(vidBundle + " VID");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Calculating...Please wait...");
        try {
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(3);
        } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
    }
}
```

An Error occurred

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:937)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1594)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2258)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2212)
    at BundlesCalculator.Main.takeInput(Main.java:65)
    at BundlesCalculator.Main.main(Main.java:43)
```

However, I wrote the same code in a simple Java Application without Gradle, there is no issue occurred.
I just wonder what did I do incorrectly?

Answer (score 0):

`Scanner` will throw that exception if there is no more input to be read.  This can happen if your input file is empty, or it doesn't contain enough data for all the `nextInt()` calls.

If input is from the terminal, you provided end-of-file (Ctrl-Z on Windows, Ctrl-D on Linux) before all the input was read.

Comment: How can I fix this? I have tried to use if (input.hasNextInt()), but the method won't accept an input from terminal. It just printed the error message I set at the else statement